# java script in build.xml : replace method

Tags: javascript, java, ant

In my java project i have build.xml and below is the code snippet :

```
<script language="javascript">
            var before = project.getProperty("VER");
            project.setProperty("SERV_VER_DB", before.replace(".", "_"));
</script>
```

the value of `project.getProperty("VER")` is `9.0.29.1` or you can say value of `before`.

I executed this build.xml in my windows machine(java1.7) as well as linux machine (java1.6). I have observed different behavior of `before.replace(".", "_")`.

In my windows the value of `SERV_VER_DB` is coming as 9_0_29_1. This means replacing all the occurrences.

In Linux the value of `SERV_VER_DB` is coming as 9_0.29.1. This means replacing first occurrence.

I couldn't understand the difference in behavior. Not sure if this is due to java version difference, or Ant version difference....

Any input please.

Comment: As i mentioned in java project build.xml, we are using above code. I know that java is not JS.

Comment: I didn't get that, and many people confuse them...